# Create Sharepoint group and assign permission, Sharepoint online

Tags: development, sharepoint-online

Using c# I would like to create a SharePoint online group and assign a permission to that group. 
According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179912.aspx
i am able to create roles,  add a user to a sharepoint group etc., but i doesnt explain how to create a sharepoint group.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try following code to Create groups:

```
    Web web = clientContext.Web;   

    GroupCreationInformation groupCreationInfo = new GroupCreationInformation();
    groupCreationInfo.Title = "Custom Group";
    groupCreationInfo.Description="Custom group created using Client Object Model";

    User owner = web.EnsureUser(@"domainName\ownerName");
    User member = web.EnsureUser(@"domainName\userName");

    Group group = web.SiteGroups.Add(groupCreationInfo);
    group.Owner = owner;
    group.Users.AddUser(member);
    group.Update();       

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```